# How to set style or font to text of a TextView in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, text, textview, android-styles

I want to set style or font to the text in a `TextView` like the image shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a custom font and then you can do this:

```
Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
MyTextView.setTypeface(mFont);
```

You have to create a "fonts" folder in your assets folder. Drop your font in there.
You could also  create a custom `TextView` of course. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633032/1333975), I gave a while back, if you prefer that.

Answer (score 12):

```
<TextView
style="@style/CodeFont"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

You need to Make that codefont style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Straight from : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 3):

There is another way if you want to change it on many TextViews, Use a class:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

}

and in the Layout replace:

```
<TextView 
...
/>
```

With:

```
<com.WHERE_YOUR_CLASS_IS.MyTextView 
...

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a layout.xml file that would have your textview in it. Something like :

```
textView.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
style="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar" >
```

If you dont want this then you could create your custom style. Something like this :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Custom" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" >
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in the layout file change the style to something like :

```
style="@style/Custom"
```