# Roboto font for Android 4+?

Tags: android, fonts, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, assets

Do I need to use Roboto font and put it to asset folder if my app will support only Android 4+ devices?

I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: Do you want to know how to it or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @silvia_aut, I want to know: do I need to use mTextView.setTypeface() every time? Or it is unnecessary, because Android 4+ uses only one parent font, so can use only xml android:typeface="normal"?

Comment: To @silvia_aut. And of couse I would like to know: Do all Android 4+ devices use Roboto font? E.g. Samsung Galaxy S4 and Google Nexus 4?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use Roboto natively from Android 4.1+ like this:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
```

For any version below that, you have to load the font yourself. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631326/use-roboto-font-in-app-with-minimum-api-level-14/14633032#14633032) answer I gave a while back for more information.

Answer (score 13):

## Answer

Ok. I think, I got it.

> Samsung phones are by far the most popular Android phones. Whilst it's
>   true that all Samsung phones from 4.1 and up have Roboto, they also
>   have something called Samsung Sans, and if your user has set it as
>   their default font then the android:font-family (as @Ahmad says)
>   requests all return Samsung Sans, not Roboto. If you have fixed tight
>   layouts with no wriggle-room that can't stretch, Samsung Sans will
>   break them. There's no easy way round this. If you absolutely have to
>   have Roboto, you must package it as an asset and set it as the
>   typeface explicitly.

Thx to @Ahmad as well as @Kenton Price's comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633032/2553905

Answer (score 4):

To add to Ahmad's excellent answer, you can swap out 'light' or 'condensed' to whichever style it is you want from the list in the Material Design guidelines here:

http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto

For example:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"     // roboto medium
```

And so on.
This comment adds no more than Ahmad's, but just clears up that you are not limited to the 3 examples he gave, you can use any.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> Ice Cream Sandwich introduced a new type family named Roboto, created
>   specifically for the requirements of UI and high-resolution screens.

Read more about [Typography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).