# TextView fonts in Android 4.x

Tags: android

I want a nice thin font for a timer in my application. Roboto Thin looks nice, but I don't know how to select it/can't find it in the layout in ADT. The choices are bold, bold|normal and bold|italic. Isn't Roboto Thin (along with other styles) available on every Android 4.x device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't Roboto Thin (along with other styles) available on every Android 4.x device?

No, only on every device running Android 4.1+. Read up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631326/use-roboto-font-in-app-with-minimum-api-level-14/14633032#14633032) I gave a while back, if you want to find out how to bring Roboto to other Android versions.