# font -family roboto android 2.3.3

Tags: android, font-family

I am trying to use the roboto fonts package for my android 2.3 app, but it does not add the fomarto letter. I've already tried using this code:

```
 TextView tvTextView =  ( TextView ) findViewById ( R . id . textView1 ); 
 Typeface typeface =  Typeface . createFromAsset ( getAssets (), "Roboto-Black.ttf" ); 
 tvTextView . setTypeface ( typeface );
```

It does not apply the letter format, how do I rotate the sources roboto android 2.3?

Comment: Are you including the Roboto-Black.ttf file in assets?

Answer (score 0):

### **There is no other way of doing this for API 11< With out including the font file in assets**

Use this TextView instead:

```
public class TextView_Roboto extends TextView {

    public TextView_Roboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            createFont();
    }

    public TextView_Roboto(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            createFont();
    }

    public TextView_Roboto(Context context) {
            super(context);
            createFont();
    }

    public void createFont() {
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "robo_font.ttf");
            setTypeface(font);
    }
 }
```

### [see full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633032/3884250)...